# How to build nginx on Ubuntu with cache_purge module?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, compiling, gcc, nginx

I have been trying to rebuild `nginx` with `cache_purge` module from [here](http://labs.frickle.com/).

I did the following and somehow the new build doesn't seem to include the module:

- Installed `nginx`
- Stopped it
- Installed build tools using:

  ```
  aptitude -y install build-essential libc6 libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libpcrecpp0 libssl0.9.8 libssl-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev lsb-base
  cd /usr/src/
  sudo wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.5.8.tar.gz
  sudo wget http://labs.frickle.com/files/ngx_cache_purge-2.1.tar.gz
  tar -xvf nginx-1.5.8.tar.gz
  tar -xvf ngx_cache_purge-2.1.tar.gz
  cd nginx-1.5.8
  ```
- Then I ran the following command after which the terminal sprouted a lot of things:

  ```
  sudo ./configure --add-module=/usr/src/ngx_cache_purge-2.1
  ```
- Thereafter, I ran the following command:

  ```
  sudo make && sudo make install
  ```

Finally though, when I run `nginx -V`, I don't see my module in the list. I see only this:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.4.1 (Ubuntu) TLS SNI support enabled configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --with-pcre-jit --with-debug --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-ipv6 --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair
--add-module=/build/buildd/nginx-1.4.1/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Can anybody help me understand if I did the build correctly?

Comment: The `nginx-naxsi` package on Debian is listed as containing the cache purge module (whatever that is). So Ubuntu must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the most recent version of nginx and cache purge, you maybe are running the installed through apt instead:

```
$ wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.5.9.tar.gz
$ wget http://labs.frickle.com/files/ngx_cache_purge-2.1.tar.gz
$ for filename in *.tar.gz; do tar zxf $filename; done
$ cd nginx*
$ ./configure --add-module=../ngx_cache_purge-2.1
(sip)
adding module in ../ngx_cache_purge-2.1
 + ngx_http_cache_purge_module was configured
(sip)
$ objs/nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.5.9
built by gcc 4.8.2 (Debian 4.8.2-16) 
configure arguments: --add-module=../ngx_cache_purge-2.1
```

Remove the version installed and everything should be alright.

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx
```

Note: I don't have nginx installed either.